# How to punctuate "from [this is a list] to [this is a list]"?

Tags: punctuation, lists

Here is an example of my specific sentence and a few idea's I've come up with.

> I experienced art in a variety of mediums, ranging from the traditional—gallery art and theater—to the informal—street murals, graffiti, and comedy.
>
> I experienced art in a variety of mediums, ranging from the traditional: gallery art and theater—to the informal: street murals, graffiti, and comedy.
>
> I experienced art in a variety of mediums, ranging from the traditional: gallery art and theater, to the informal: street murals, graffiti, and comedy.

Are there any hard and fast rules to punctuating this type of sentence? If not, which punctuation seems most natural?

Answer (score 3):

The first one is pretty good. You might also consider parentheses:

> I experienced art in a variety of mediums, ranging from the traditional (gallery art and theater) to the informal (street murals, graffiti, and comedy.)